# Number of paths of lenght K in hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

An $n$-dimensional hypercube is defined as a directed graph consisting of $2^n$ vertices, numbered from $0$ to $2^n -1$. There is an edge from $x$ to y iff $x < y$ and there is only $1$ different bit in the binary representation of these two numbers. (also can be represented as $x \text{ XOR } y = 2^p$ where $p$ is any natural number).

The task I have is to find the number of paths of length $K$ in the graph. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Hi. What is the degree of each vertex? So in each step of the path how many choices do you have to go along?

Comment: @Phicar: Note that the graph here is *directed* and not regular (different vertices have different out-degrees).  It is possible you realize this, but your Comment might suggest to the OP that all vertices have equal degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertex has as many outgoing paths as there are $0$s in its number.  Starting from a vertex with $m\ 0$ bits, there are $\frac {m!}{(m-K)!}$ paths, so the total number of paths of length $K$ is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-K}{n \choose i}\frac {i!}{(i-K)!}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-K}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\frac {i!}{(i-K)!}$$